# Fill array of objects from ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core

I've ConcurrentDictionary as following code:

`public ConcurrentDictionary<long, User> Users { get; set; }`

User Class:

```
public partial class User
    {
        [JsonProperty("parentId")]
        public long ParentId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("firstName")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("userType")]
        public long UserType { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("accountId")]
        public long AccountId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("userName")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }
    }
```

And array as following code: 
`public Node[] Data { get; set; }`

Node class:

```
public partial class Node
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("parent")]
        public long Parent { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("text")]
        public string Text { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("state", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public State State { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("icon")]
        public Uri Icon { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to copy User objects from ConcurrentDictionary into an array of Node objects, So some properties of the User object should be moved to Node object:

```
Node[] Data = new Node[]
{
  Id = user.Id,
  Parent = user.ParentId,
  Text = user.FirstName
}
```

Is there a way to do that without **looping**, Thanks.

Comment: why ``Parent `` is string and ``Text `` is long in ``Node`` class?must have the same type like a ``User``?

Comment: Thanks, buddy, I've modified ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**Linq**](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions):

1. Take values from dictionary
2. Select new `Node` by converting some properties from `User` to `Node`
3. `.ToArray()` to convert `IEnumerable` to `Array`, like the following code:

```
Node[] Data = Users.Values
    .Select(x => new Node { Id = x.Id, Parent = x.ParentId, Text = x.FirstName })
    .ToArray();
```

I hope this helps you out.

Comment: @AmmarSaleh : can you check my answer?

Comment: I will check and tell you.